# Extracting numbers from string directly for division

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have downloaded and created the dataframe below. I would like to create an additional column, in which I divide the second number from a cell by the first one. To give an example, the first cell of the column should be 0.8 (because it's 4/5 = 0.8). Does anyone know how to get the numbers from the string directly and divide them?

[image]

Thanks in advance, any help or tips appreciated

Comment: kindly post data, not pics. [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: thanks a lot, I will do so in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df['Ratio'] = (df['Ratio'].str.split(' for ', expand=True)
                          .astype(float)
                          .assign(Ratio= lambda x: x[0] / x[1])['Ratio'])
```